# Print a webpage using CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I have a question,that would be the best solution to print a webpage.For example, I have a website with news,I need to print only the news and picture,and remove the menu,header and footer.I want to do this in CodeIgniter.

Comment: You can use JavaScript `window.print()` method to print the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said *you want to this in CodeIgniter*. I don't think you need any server side code for this. Try below suggestion.

You can use `@media` query.

In your default css without using external stylesheet you can do this:

```
@media print {
    #with_print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Hide your header, footer and menu withing `@media print` block

With external stylesheet add `media="print"` attribute to `<link>` tag.

```
<link href='printCSS.css' rel='stylesheet' media="print" type='text/css'>
```

With external stylesheet you don't need to add `@media` query block in your `printCSS.css`.

See the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3av7e/3/)**

See the print preview from your browser and where the text says:
`I will be hidden when you try to print me`, cannot not be seen on the print preview page.

Comment: Hi sir, where can I get the printCSS.css file